# Boards equals 0

Tags: java, int

i have 1 problem with int boards.
When I'm adding a new int in while loop all of int equals 0.

```
public class Enemy extends Render {
    private int X[] = new int[64];
    private int Y[] = new int[64];
    private int i = 1;
    public Enemy(int x, int y, int num1, int num2) { 
        //x = 480, y = 360, num2 = 2
        X[num1-1] = x;
        Y[num1-1] = y;
        while(i <= num2) {
            System.out.println(X[0]+" "+Y[0]+" "+X[1]+" "+Y[1]);
            i++;
        }
        i = 1;
    }
}
```

1st and 2nd line of print equals 480 360 0 0, next prints equals 0 0 30 360
I need to have 480 360 480 360 pls help.

Comment: `int[] numbers = new int[5];` .. `System.out.println(numbers[0]);` That would print 0 as well. An array of integers without setting a value will have 0 by default.

Comment: When class is 1st time performed it's 1 if class is 2nd time performed it's 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

int[] numbers = new int[5]; .. System.out.println(numbers[0]); That would print 0 as well. An array of integers without setting a value will have 0 by default.

If you receive `x = 480, y = 360, num2 = 2` (we don't know num1), lets assume num1=1

```
X[num1-1] = x;
Y[num1-1] = y;
```

this would be

X[1-1] = x; //X[0] = 480 
Y[1-1] = y; //Y[0] = 360

Now...

```
   while(i <= num2) {
        System.out.println(X[0]+" "+Y[0]+" "+X[1]+" "+Y[1]);
        i++;
    }
```

Here you are always printing the same values regardless of i, so if you have not yet set a value for those elements then they will always be 0.

There you will print 480, 360 and then 0, 0 since you only have set values for the array in the position 0. The ones in the position 1 are not yet set, 0 by default.

I don't know what do you mean by: `next output equals 0 0 30 360`

But maybe you wanted something like this...

```
...
```

//If num1 is 1 then it will fill up X[0] and X[1] with x.
        X[num1-1] = x;
        Y[num1-1] = y;

```
    X[num1] = x;
    Y[num1] = y;
..
           // Out of bounds risky here, make sure you have enough elements before calling i+1 index.
            System.out.println(X[i]+" "+Y[i]+" "+X[i+1]+" "+Y[i+1]);
...
```

But make sure you don't cause an out of bounds.

Now, if you sent num1=2 then

```
X[2-1] = x; //X[1] = 480
Y[2-1] = y; //Y[1] = 360
```

There you are not setting the value for the element with index 0, so it will preserve the default value, 0.

Comment: I had extend main class with Enemy class

Answer (score 0):

You're not putting values into any elements of the arrays except in element `num1-1`.

Should your `if` be a `while` instead?

Where you have:

```
X[num1-1] = x;
Y[num1-1] = y;
```

You instead need something more like:

```
for(int i=0;i<X.length;i++){
    X[i] = x;
    Y[i] = y;
 }
```

Comment: Sry for my errors in code, edited!

Comment: My answer should be more clear now.  You're currently not initializing anything except X[0] and Y[0].